# Should be a Spring Service null safe?

Tags: java, spring, exception, null

Should I validate each parameter in a service method and throw `IllegalArgumentException` in case of a wrong parameter? Or should `null` checks always occur at higher plane (e.g. Controller)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the validations of the POJO bean class, then consider Spring Bean Validation framework:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Also please refer the below example:

http://howtodoinjava.com/2015/02/12/spring-bean-validation-example-with-jsr-303-annotations/

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not related to Spring, but business components in general. The proper answer is: it depends.

1. It depends on the size of your system - are you the sole user of your own business components or not. If the codebase is very small, then you can *assume* you are using your own code in a proper way.
2. It depends on how your code is organised - if you have very clear access points to some modules, then detailed validation should happen on the boundaries/access points of such modules.
3. It depends if business compoents accept raw data from user (for example through RestControllers). If such is the case, most of the validation should happen on the controller level and the user should be informed as early as possible about invalid data. In case when business component can be accessed in more than one way (vide Hexagonal Architecture) then it should also validate input data.

It would be the best to describe the problem you are trying to solve, then our answers would be more suited to your problem at hand.

As for VA31's answer: first decide what to do, only then think about right tool for the job. 'What' is usually more important than 'how'.